condition to fit the derivative inside an operator $\dfrac{d}{dt} Ex(t) = E\dfrac{d}{dt} x(t)$ (abstract ODE)
I have an operator $E: X \longrightarrow Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are Hilbert spaces and $E$ is a linear and bounded operator, but not necessarily inversible.
I would like to know under what conditions can we fit the derivative inside the operator? that is to say when $\dfrac{d}{dt} Ex(t) = E\dfrac{d}{dt} x(t)$ where $x(t)\in X$.
To add context, I wanted to know if the solution of this abstract ODE (it's call DAE) $\dfrac{d}{dt} Ex(t) = Ax(t)$ with $t>=0$ has the same solution as   $E\dfrac{d}{dt} x(t) = Ax(t)$. And since X and Y are Hilbert spaces, it is customary to assume that x(t) is a function

This is far too vague. Are the elements of $X$ and $Y$ functions of $t$?

use the definition of $\frac{d}{dt}$ as limit of difference quotients, apply linearity of $E$ and then make a continuity argument by boundedness

@TedShifrin sorry but this isn't vague at all.

@Max I disagree. If the elements of $X$ and $Y$ are indeed functions of $t$, then your argument is wrong. If $t$  is an external parameter, then of course I agree with your argument.

no they are hilbert spaces

For linear maps $E$  product rule applies $$\partial_t(E \cdot x) = (\partial_t E) \cdot x + E\cdot \partial_t x  $$

$L^2(\Bbb R)$ is a Hilbert space. And I'm thinking of functions of $t$.

what you mean is  $x\in\mathrm{C^{1}(\mathbb{R},X)}$ but this is rather obvious

@RolandF if $E$ is an operator, not a factor. By "slopply notation" sometimes either the brackets or the concatination operator are sometimes omitted which can lead to missunderstandings since also multiplication is often omitted by sloppy notation.

@TedShifrin I give you that one, it might be even more sloppy notation (often also found in books especially in engineering) not correctly distinguishing between function spaces and the image spaces of functions. In dubio pro reo let me assume $x$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $X$. This is something only the OP can answer

A linear operator applies by dot-multiplication per $$\text{row} \cdot \text{column}$$ like scalar products in any basis. Product rule applies to dot products per component. Don't' worry.

Now you are mixing up linear operators and their representation in the form of matrix operations in the finite dimensional case. If you dont konw what i mean think about it as matrix multiplication but just assume $E$ does not depend on $t$.

To add context, I wanted to know if the solution of this abstract ODE (it's call DAE) $\dfrac{d}{dt} Ex(t) = Ax(t)$ with $t>=0$ has the same solution as   $E\dfrac{d}{dt} x(t) = Ax(t)$. And since X and Y are Hilbert spaces, it is customary to assume that x(t) is a function
